# Git Fix History from Reflog

Tags: git

I'm fairly new at git, and I think I want to use rebase to fix my messed up history.

Here's my Git reflog. I want to make 2f6803d the most current commit, and have the history go 2f6803d fe6ab04 4f99c5d a335e24, without the stupid soft reset that I shouldn't have done. Also I'd like to change the commit message for 2f6803d so that it's got it's own message, instead of "foo." I think this is what rebase is for, but, like I said, I'm a noob here. How do I go about removing the bad commits from the history? The current state of my repo is the same as 2f6803d, and I'm able to work locally fine, but I can't push it because the soft reset at HEAD@{4} means it's not current with the repo.

I just cloned the remote repo, copied the current local repo over, and everything was fine, but I'd like to understand the git way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

```
2f6803d (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 2f6803d
---some bad commits---
2f6803d (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{3}: commit: foo
4f99c5d HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD~ (This was my mistake!)
fe6ab04 (origin/master) HEAD@{5}: commit: foo
4f99c5d HEAD@{6}: commit: bar
a335e24 HEAD@{7}: commit: baz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `HEAD` to `master` and `master` to commit `2f6803d`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 2f6803d # warning: remove uncommitted changes
git log # to check the history
```

To edit the commit message of the last commit (currently `2f6803d`):

```
git commit --amend
```